# Use custom attributes for input on Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to use custom attributes on inputs and divs. When I put static data like this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" custom-data='12345' />
```

The code works fine. But when I use data from a loop for example:

```
<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" custom-data='{{ data.id }}' />
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'custom-data' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" [ERROR ->]custom-data='{{ data.id }}' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use the bracket notation when setting inputs to an expression:

`<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" [custom-data]="data.id" />`

Comment: how to get this custom data in .ts file and alert it (click)="test()"

Answer (score 0):

remove the curly brackets and add the value

```
<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" custom-data='data.id ' />
```

since `custom-data` is a directive no need to use the curly brackets when you are binding values to directive attributes